# Haskell Servant - is there a way to compose API types?

Tags: web-services, rest, haskell, servant

I know this isn't valid syntax, but is there a way to accomplish something like this in servant?

```
type StandardAPI = "foo" :> Get '[JSON] Whatever

type CustomAPI = StandardAPI :<|> "customroute" :> Get '[JSON] Blah
```

in other words, composing APIs. In Spock I could do this with the monadic route construction, but I'm not sure how to do this in servant.

This way I can reuse shared routes across APIs. Another reason to use this is that there are certain types that don't work with client generators, such as Raw.

Comment: This looks like valid syntax. What exactly do you want to do that `:>` doesn't do? That does compose apis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, referencing [Servant documentation](http://haskell-servant.github.io/tutorial/0.4/server.html#nested-apis) you can use

```
type CombinedAPI = "users" :> UsersAPI
          :<|> "products" :> ProductsAPI

server :: Server CombinedAPI
server = usersServer :<|> productsServer

usersServer :: Server UsersAPI
usersServer = -- implementation

productsServer :: Server ProductsAPI
productsServer = -- implementation
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without the top level "users" in the route? The problem is that code generated by servant-JS no longer works because it doesn't correspond to CombinedAPI. I can't run writeJSForAPI on my equivalent of CombinedAPI because it includes a Raw combinator which doesn't have a GenerateList instance.

Comment: Sorry, cannot answer that question right now. best way to test it is to try it. I don't think  `UsersAPI :<|> "products" :> ProductsAPI` is invalid thing to do

Comment: you're right it is valid. to do that following your example and excluding the top level piece of the route. wasn't compiling because I had the ordering mixed up in the implementation definition.

Comment: Glad that everything is sorted out!